# How do I serve static content with thorntail

Tags: java, thorntail

I have a new project created using the [Thorntail Project Generator](https://thorntail.io/generator/). I want to serve a small amount of static files such as html, images etc

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you build your project with Maven, you need to:

- make sure that your Maven project is `<packaging>war</packaging>`
- add a dependency on the `io.thorntail:undertow` fraction
- put your static content into `src/main/webapp` (but not under `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF`)
- if you also use JAX-RS, make sure that the JAX-RS application is not bound to `/`; for example, if you use the most common way of enabling JAX-RS (creating an `Application` subclass with the `@ApplicationPath` annotation), make sure that you don't have `@ApplicationPath("/")`, but something like `@ApplicationPath("/api")`

I created a small example project here: https://github.com/rhoar-qe/thorntail-test-suite/tree/master/javaee/static-content

Note that Thorntail is based on WildFly, and so includes the same servlet container: Undertow. If you have more elaborate needs, you can find articles about serving static content with servlet in general and Undertow in particular everywhere on the web, including here on StackOverflow.